# Run powershell script as custom command inside cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

How can I run a PowerShell script as a custom command from cmd or powershell.

For example my script (CreateFile.ps1):

```
function CreateFile ($fileName) {
    New-Item -Name $fileName -ItemType "file"    
}

CreateFile($args[0])
```

I would like to use the script in cmd\powershell with a custom command (here as "CF"):

```
C:\some folder> CF testfile.txt
```

I added a new system environment variable with a link to my ps1 file. But it won't work, even after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 'CF filename' in PowerShell and cmd I suggest you use in cmd a batch file placed somewhere in your path:

```
:: CF.cmd create file %1 with 0 length
@Type Nul >"%~1"
```

And put a function in one of your PowerShell profiles `$PROFILE | Format-List -Force`

```
function CF ($fileName) {
    New-Item -Name $fileName -ItemType "file"    
}
```

So you have the same command but executed in their respective environment.

Answer (score 0):

> I added a new system environment variable with a link to my ps1 file.

From *outside of PowerShell* its scripts (`*.ps1`) are by design *not* directly executable (unlike batch files (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`), so making `*.ps1` scripts available via `$env:PATH` is not sufficient if you want to call them from `cmd.exe`

However, you can write a simple, auxiliary wrapper batch file that invokes your script explicitly via `powershell.exe`:

In one of the folders listed in `$env:PATH`:

- create batch file `CF.cmd` with the following content:

  ```
  @powershell.exe -NoProfile -File "%~dp0CreateFile.ps1" %*
  ```
- copy `CreateFile.ps1` to the *same folder*, but *remove the function wrapper* so that the calling the script invokes the functionality directly; i.e., make its content the following:

  ```
  param($FileName)

  New-Item -Name $FileName -ItemType File
  ```

You will then be able to call `CF` (`CF.cmd`) from both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell.
From within PowerShell, however, calling `CreateFile` (`CreateFile.ps1`) directly is more efficient.